# Laravel получить ссылку с параметрами за исключением определенного параметра

Tags: php, laravel

Как в Laravel получить ссылку с параметрами за исключением определенного параметра? К примеру с ссылки вида: `site.com/category?page=2&sort=price&by=asc`
Получить `site.com/category?sort=price&by=asc`

Answer (score 1):

Если `site.com/category?page=2&sort=price&by=asc` - текущая страница, то получить ссылку `site.com/category?sort=price&by=asc` можно следующим образом:

```
$url = URL::route(Route::current()->getName(), Request::except('page'));
```

Не забудьте добавить в начало файла

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```